# Exporting variable to CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv, random, numbers, export

I am in the process of creating a simple random number generator in python for a school project. This is what I have so far:

```
import random

amnt = input('Please enter the amount of numbers you would like:')
for i in range(0,amnt):


          x = random.randint(0,100000000)
          print x
```

This has the desired result, it generates a set amount of random numbers based on the user input. The problem I need to solve now is how to export the numbers generated into one CSV file so that they can be analysed. I believe that the CSV module needs to be imported and implemented but I am not sure how to do this. I am trying to analyze the effectiveness of the random module in order to write an essay so being able to use excel to sort and filter the numbers would be very helpful. Any changes or modifications to the code would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any datastructure, CSV don't allow you to store meaningless data.

Comment: You need to make a list then read: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples and https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples

Comment: @rednaks: If the data consists of only one value per line, then no additional "data structuring" would be needed for it to be considered a valid csv file. @thesctt: Just open a file and use `file.write(str(x) + '\n')` to write lines to it.

Comment: Okey, you're right, sorry :)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the links they will be helpful. I am very new to this so I am kinda confused. How would I store this data in a list? From my limited knowledge and research I would have to separate every number with a comma in order to create the list but I'm not sure how to do that because all of the numbers are from one variable. My end goal is to create a program that will export a set of random numbers to a file that can then be sorted in excel so that I can analyze it, would exporting to a CSV file be the appropriate way to go about this or do you have a more effective solution?

Answer (score 4):

You just need a one line code to convert a variable to csv format.
Let me know if this does not work.
If the code works for you please rate the answer.

```
x.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't really the `csv` module for a case this simple. You just need to create a text file in which the values are separated  by commas. (Hence the name, Comma-Separated Values, CSV).

Try this:

```
import random

amnt = int(raw_input('Please enter the amount of numbers you would like:'))
data = (random.randint(0,100000000) for _ in range(amnt))
data = (str(datum) for datum in data)
data = ','.join(data) + '\n'
with open("random.csv", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import csv

amnt = input('Please enter the amount of numbers you would like:')
ofile  = open('ttest.csv', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',')
for i in range(0,amnt):
    x = random.randint(0,100000000)
    writer.writerow([x])
ofile.close()
```

Might be a quick solution to your problem. `writerow` will write a row to your csv. Since you want to open it in excel I wrote one number/row, so you can order it based on the column.

However, you could also sort the numbers programatically without having to use excel. As some already mentioned CSV is especially aimed for storing data structures.

More info can be found in the [csv module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)